# What does "character scaling" refer to in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was reading an [guide on wowhead](https://www.wowhead.com/guides/holy-paladin-azerite-essences#essencesminor-mid-tier) which mentioned:

> That being said due to how **paladins scale** the Intellect proc doesn't provide as much value as other alternatives in terms of raw HPS.

Emphasis mine. What does this mean? And how does one figure out/calculate this? Is it the same for all classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Scale" in this case refers to "Scaling with stats" -- or, put more simply for this case, "How the Holy Paladin's ability to heal improves for a given increase in a specific stat" (Which are acquired from stronger gear, or temporary boosts, such as are being discussed in the guide).

While I can't speak to the specifics about healing as a Holy Paladin, the implication is that the effect of this ability (the bonus **Intellect**) is less useful to a Paladin than another stat -- such as **Critical** rating or **Mastery**.

Unfortunately, there is no general way to determine this, as each class is different, and often that there are multiple potential interactions between spells, abilities, buffs, etc. to truly account for a "Standard" situation.

That doesn't mean people don't give it a try, and the folks over on [Icy-Veins](https://www.icy-veins.com/wow/class-guides), for instance, have gone after the problem with more spreadsheets than you can swing an arcanite reaper at.